# Prevent Midnight Commander opening files on mouse click?

Tags: mc

I use to accidentally doubleclick an archive on a remote FS (in a FISH panel) and then it starts being downloaded to be opened - very annoying. Can I prevent MC opening files with the mouse to avoid this?

It would also be nice to totally forbid opening remote files with <kbd>Enter</kbd> (I don't mean <kbd>F3</kbd> or <kbd>F4</kbd> - those are fine) leaving explicit download (copy to local) the only option.

Answer (score 5):

You can disable mouse support using using the *-d* option when invoking the Midnight Commander.